# How to load rejson.so with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, redis

I want to store json type in Redis, so I set up for using RedisJSON module with docker-compose. But, I keep failing on running it. The code is below.
I also tried to use redis.conf that is filled with same parameters as command, but Segmentation fault was occured.
What's wrong on my step?

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    image: redis:7.0.0-alpine
    command: redis-server --loadmodule /etc/redis/modules/rejson.so
    volumes:
      - /etc/redis/redis.conf:/etc/redis/redis.conf
      - /etc/redis/modules/rejson.so:/etc/redis/modules/rejson.so
```

#### Environment

Node.js Version: 16.14.1 
Node Redis Version: 4.0.6 
Platform: Mac OS 12.3.1

---

#### *Edited*

Segmentation fault was because of unexisting `includes` option.
Below messages were repeated.
What it means **Exec format error**?

```markdown
# oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
# Redis version=7.0.0, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
# Configuration loaded
* monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
# Warning: Could not create server TCP listening socket ::1:6380: bind: Address not available
* Running mode=standalone, port=6380.
# Server initialized
# Module /etc/redis/modules/rejson.so failed to load: Error loading shared library /etc/redis/modules/rejson.so: Exec format error
# Can't load module from /etc/redis/modules/rejson.so: server aborting
```

Comment: Do you have more information on the error besides it being a segmentation fault? Maybe paste it into the question?

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of trial and error, I found out that as of this time, the redis v7 docker images seem to lack the rejson module.

I am now using redis/stack-server which already includes all modules (including) rejson. It is based upon redis v6, see:

- [redis/redis-stack](https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack) for DEV/TST or
- [redis/redis-stack-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack-server) for PRD

My `compose.yaml` now looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis/redis-stack
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data:rw
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  redis_data:
```

In the redis-cli you can then give it a try:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET employee_profile $ '{ "employee": { "name": "alpha", "age": 40,"married": true }  } '
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.GET employee_profile
"{\"employee\":{\"name\":\"alpha\",\"age\":40,\"married\":true}}"
```

If you still have Docker volumes from previous installations, you should delete them first. Otherwise your new container might get problems reading an older database.